# Embedded YouTube Video in HTML not visible on front end

Tags: html, youtube, html5-video, embed, visibility

I am facing visiblity issue of embedded youtube video in HTML on frontend. Although while inspecting the same it is visible, moreover it is visible on Mobile too. But on desktop I am not able to view it at once. Code used to embed the video mentioned below.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1q3Gj.png)

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: <iframe class="embed-responsive-item" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/6KamS4u3pYI"></iframe>

Used this iframe tags to embed the youtube video.

Comment: [https://wizfinityedusolutions.com/ets-toefl/] On this page I am facing problem. On first visit the video section is not visible. But once we inspect the same video appears.
I want to make it visible at first visit only without inspecting.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```css
iframe{
  width:100vw;
  height:100vh;
  
}
*{
  margin:0px;
  padding:0px;
}
```

```html
<iframe src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/S94JdUwKHLU" title="YouTube video player" frameborder="0" allow="accelerometer; autoplay; clipboard-write; encrypted-media; gyroscope; picture-in-picture" allowfullscreen></iframe>
```